# How Can i rid of the red lines while declaring variables in .scss file in VS code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass, scss-lint

[image]

Getting this red lines while declaring the variables in .scss file in VS Code.

The error I'm getting:
[image]

I tried different configurations in settings in vs code but its not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to select language mode to scss in you vs code.
[image: Same error]
Go to bottom panel and find language mode selector.
[image: Bottom panale vs code]
Press this button and in a pop-up there type scss and change language mode to scss.
[image: vs code pop-up]
That should do the trick.